# How to set -javaagent in spark-submit

Tags: shell, apache-spark, sh, jvm-arguments, javaagents

I have used aspect-oriented programming to do the logging in a Java Maven project.

While running it through eclipse I have to initialize javaagent in vmargs, as follows:

```
    -javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar
```

Now I want to submit the jar produced to a Spark worker. I have written a shell script to do it. I am able to run but unable to initialize javaagent.

```
export SPARK_PATH=/xyz
export SPARK_URL=spark://abc:0000
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:../aspectweaver-1.9.1.jar"
$SPARK_PATH/spark-submit --master $SPARK_URL  --jars  --class com.main.index ../index-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I have tried number of examples like setting JAVA_OPTS and CATALINE_OPTS, creating spark-env.sh and setting it. But none of this worked. Struggling from last 3 days.

I checked few similar questions on stackoverflow but none of the were helpful in setting javaagent. Help.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I am checking if javaagent is initialized in code using below code:

```
try {
            org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Agent.getInstrumentation();
        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError | UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

I get the NoClassDefFoundError. Which concludes that javaagent is not set.

Comment: `JAVA_OPTS="JAVA_OPTS …` should probably be `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS …`.

Comment: @Biffen Typo. I have made sure syntax was right. I have even tried something like %JAVA_OPTS% which I had checked out in one of the blogs. None of them helped.

Comment: Spark has a driver and executors. They have separate JAVA_OPTS

Comment: @cricket_007 How can I solve it? Is there a way to set JAVA_OPTS for both driver and executors?

Comment: search for `extraJavaOptions` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment

Comment: @cricket_007 no luck with this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer for this, I had to use "--driver-java-options". Below is the updated script.

```
$SPARK_PATH/spark-submit --master $SPARK_URL --driver-java-options "-javaagent:../aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar" --class com.main.index ../index-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar "$1"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that option is copied into `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`configuration